# Covering functions with Istanbul and Mocha/Chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, mocha.js, istanbul

I am having trouble understanding how to unit test functions so that istanbul will consider them covered.

For an extremely simply example, I created this math module:

```
var add = function( one, two ){
    return one + two;
}

module.exports = {
    add: add
};
```

and basic unit testing:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('add() method', function(){
    it('should do math', function(){
        expect( some.add(1, 1) ).to.equal(2);
    });
});
```

The report produced by istanbul gives me these results:

- Statements: 66.67% (2 / 3)
- Branches: 100% (0 / 0)
- Functions: 0% (0 / 1)
- Lines: 66.67% (2 / 3)
- Ignored: none

[image]

If simply testing the result of calling the function doesn't count as coverage, how are you supposed to test this code when it is in a function scope your unit tests can't access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all the toughest problems, this was caused by something stupid and unrelated.

I was running istanbul through grunt and was using the `env` workaround so the correct directory is used when checking coverage. As in something like this:

```
env: {
    coverage: {
        APP_DIR_FOR_CODE_COVERAGE: '../test/coverage/instrument/app/'
    }
},
```

*As shown in the [grunt-istanbul documentation](https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul#documentation)*

The problem was that I forgot to include `env:coverage` in the task I created for running the coverage tests.

Anyway, if you have this same problem you probably did something really stupid too.